# SQL Server query to remove the last word from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's already an answer for this question in SO with a MySQL tag. So I just decided to make your lives easier and put the answer below for SQL Server users. Always happy to see different answers perhaps with a better performance.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString, 1, LEN(@YourString) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@YourString)))
```

Edit: Make sure `@YourString` is trimmed first as Alex M has pointed out:

```
SET @YourString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@YourString))
```

Comment: Won't this just replace all instances of the last word? You're better off taking the idea of this and improving it with something like `SUBSTRING(string, 1, LEN(string) - charindex(' ', REVERSE(string))`

Comment: Thank you @ZLK I've edited the answer as per your comment. Looks much cleaner. Sorry it took a while to give you the credit.

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to answers.

The doc for `LEN` function in MSSQL:

> LEN excludes trailing blanks. If that is a problem, consider using the DATALENGTH (Transact-SQL) function which does not trim the string. If processing a unicode string, DATALENGTH will return twice the number of characters.

The problem with the answers here is that trailing spaces are not accounted for.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@YourString, 1, LEN(@YourString) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@YourString)))
```

As an example few inputs for the accepted answer (above for reference), which would have wrong results:

```
   INPUT        ->   RESULT
   'abcd  '     ->   'abc'        --last symbol removed
   'abcd 123 '  ->   'abcd 12'    --only removed only last character
```

To account for the above cases one would need to trim the string (would return the last word out of 2 or more words in the phrase):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(@YourString), 1, LEN(@YourString) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@YourString)))))
```

The reverse is trimmed on both sides, that is to account for the leading as well as trailing spaces.

Or alternatively, just trim the input itself.

Comment: I'm editing the accepted answer thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Shouldn't LEN(Name) be LEN(@YourString)?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Sentence    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Hi This is Pavan Kumar'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Sentence, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Sentence) - 1) AS [First Word],
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Sentence), 1, 
               CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Sentence)) - 1)) AS [Last Word]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'One two three four'

SELECT LEFT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@String),0)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far are actually about removing a character, not a word as the OP wanted.

In my case I was building a dynamic SQL statement with `UNION`'d `SELECT` statements and wanted to remove the last `UNION`:

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
/* populate @sql with something like this:
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T1 WHERE condition
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T2 WHERE condition
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T3 WHERE condition
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T4 WHERE condition
    UNION
*/
-- remove the last UNION
SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - PATINDEX(REVERSE('%UNION%'), REVERSE(@sql)) - LEN('UNION'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(username , LEN(json_path) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(username ))+1) 
FROM Login_tbl
```

```
UPDATE Login_tbl 
SET username = LEFT(username , LEN(json_path) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(username ))+1)
```

Answer (score -2):

DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(MAX) = 'One two three four'

SELECT LEFT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@String),0)+1)

Comment: Your answer has the exact same content @mindbdev s!