# Grabbing last word from query

Tags: mysql, sql

[SQL Server query to remove the last word from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914021/sql-server-query-to-remove-the-last-word-from-a-string)

Very similar to this problem, but how would you write a SQL statement to grab just the last word of a string instead of removing it.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Here is some sentence', ' ', -1);
```

This would output `sentence`.

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_SUBSTR` provides another option:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Here is some sentence', '\\S+$');
```